# ComboBox bound to Enum using IValueConverter loses SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, enums

I have a combobox bound to an enum, which works fine, but when I use an `IValueConverter` to make the enum value more friendly, there is no longer a default selected item in the combobox. Any ideas?

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(InstallerAction), typeof(string))]
    public class InstallerActionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value produced by the binding source.</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target property.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
        /// </returns>
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var installerActions = (InstallerAction[])value;
            var result = new List<string>();

            foreach(var item in installerActions)
            {
                switch (item)
                {
                    case InstallerAction.Install:
                        result.Add("Install");
                        break;
                    case InstallerAction.None:
                        result.Add("None");
                        break;
                    case InstallerAction.UninstallAll:
                        result.Add("Uninstall All");
                        break;
                    case InstallerAction.UninstallOne:
                        result.Add("Uninstall One");
                        break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The value that is produced by the binding target.</param>
        /// <param name="targetType">The type to convert to.</param>
        /// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter to use.</param>
        /// <param name="culture">The culture to use in the converter.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A converted value. If the method returns null, the valid null value is used.
        /// </returns>
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var installerActions = (string)value;

            switch (installerActions)
            {
                case "None":
                    return InstallerAction.None;
                case "Install":
                    return InstallerAction.Install;
                case "Uninstall One":
                    return InstallerAction.UninstallOne;
                case "Uninstall All":
                    return InstallerAction.UninstallAll;
                default:
                    return InstallerAction.None;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseInfos}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10">
                    <ListView.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.Resources>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Action">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ActionFromEnum}, Converter={StaticResource InstallerActionConverter}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Action}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>

                            ...
```

Comment: ItemsSource is of type string but SelectedItem is still bound to enum. Both should be consistent i.e. if ItemsSource is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, selected item should be of type `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Converter to your SelectedItem binding as well.

Comment: I ended up using two converters: one for the `ItemsSource` (`MyEnum[]`) and one for `SelectedItem` (`MyEnum`)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using converter to bind item source and then selected item as well,
You can try only setting the Item Template for combo box item in order to display friendly name.